# Memory overloading, very high memory swap amount

Tags: sql-server-2008, memory, windows-server-2008

We run a server at work using a program called Shipworks, we are an ecommerce company, so aids us in shipping our orders.

We have been having intermittent issues with latency in shipping labels printing and searches through the program(which uses a sql database) when all our users are on. We have between 8 - 12 users actively on shipworks.

Our server has 8gb of RAM and a quad core processor. I was using new relic to monitor the server to determine the issue and it looks like memory amounts are going beyond where they should be.

Screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/2j5bga0/5

My memory is staying at a constant 8600 mb of system swap Ram and 5400 MB of Used RAM. The server only has 8gb of RAM but this sounds like it is using around 14gb I know there is virtual RAM but there has to be something wrong here. If anyone can help, it'd be much appreciated

Comment: Couple of things you could try, depending on your technical proficiency. One is doing traces via SQL Server, where you can filter for criteria like time to run and resource usage. Another is to download WinDBG and attach it to the process and unpick where bottlenecks are. I'm not sure what 'new relic' is, but you might want to give http://sourceforge.net/projects/hyperic-hq/ a try as an intermediate step. Your ram usage is fine, and swap on disk is always the same size as your installed RAM so that's ok too. My guess would be a SQL issue, you might need to calve off some old data.

Comment: you mean purge my tables right? Is there a correlation between database size and process amounts? Even if I query a smaller table, would the process amount be higher due to the database size?

Comment: SQL Server has a bunch of optimizations for coping with this kind of thing. To answer your questions, no overall database size doesn't have an effect on individual query performance. so if you have a table thats grown huge, and don't need that data anymore, you can just rename the table and then re-create it as the old name that ShipWorks needs. You've got to be careful with id columns and the like though, this really isn't and end-user thing it should be ShipWorks support looking into it.

Comment: I found this link if it helps: https://shipworks.com/support/viewtopic.php?p=44416&sid=c6962c746618abdcdda3bf19796b9279. If you're still on SQL Express it might be worth paying for the standard install.

Comment: one thing you can do is profile your queries at peak load, find which ones are taking the longest; then try adding some indexes to the relevant tables to help SQL Server run the queries quicker.

Comment: once last tip, you might find more love at the sister site serverfault.com. you're after sysadmins, not programmers for these kinds of problems

Comment: Thank you @user326608 I wasn't aware of the sister site either, and to add on we are on SQL express. Just realized it today. We are debating on switching to sql standard but it doesn't come very cheap. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that what we needed was the upgrade from sql express to standard. We just got it up yesterday and everything is going great now. Thanks guys